# htaccess rewrite to subfolder not masking

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, masking

I want to redirect `https://example.com/folder` to `https://example.com/otherfolder/anotherfolder` but have the address bar still display `https://example.com/folder`.

None of the `.htaccess` tutorials on doing this work, and the only ones I can find on StackOverflow are much more complicated problems.

So far I have tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^folder/?$ /otherfolder/anotherfolder
```

I get a rewrite/redirect but the URL is not masked.

Edit: Solved, see below. Missing trailing slash.

Comment: Both rules do not implement an external redirection. Actually they are identically. Which suggests that either you did not really show here what you actually implemented, or that the issue is not with those rules but with the way you test.

Comment: Keep in mind to always test using a fresh anonymous browser window to prevent client side caching issues during your tests. And always use the networking console your browser offers to actually see the technical response you receive back from your http server.

Comment: I'm trying to accomplish an *internal* redirect with masking. Is that not possible?

The code shown is exactly as I have it in the .htaccess file.

I have tested using four different browsers in order to avoid cache issues. I get consistent redirects but no masking.

Comment: Yes, certainly that is possible. And as said those rules you posted do implement that. Which is why I wrote what you can see above.

Comment: Please post the combination of requests and responses you get on the test requests. So including all headers. Copy them from your browser's console and add them to the question itself. There is an "edit" link below your question, use it to add information.

Comment: What you are trying to accomplish is actually _not_ a redirection at all, but an internal _rewrite_ .

Comment: And, by the way, what http server are you using for those tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^folder/?$ /otherfolder/anotherfolder
> ```

I assume `/otherfolder/anotherfolder` must be a physical filesystem directory (from the name "folder" and the fact there wouldn't ordinarily be a way to route the request otherwise). In which case you are missing a trailing slash on the *substitution* string (target URL).

Without the trailing slash, mod_dir will trigger an external 301 redirect to append the trailing slash and expose the rewritten filesystem directory so you will ultimately see an external redirect to `/otherfolder/anotherfolder/` (note the trailing slash).

Note that this would be a 301 (permanent) redirect and cached persistently by the browser.

So, the rule should be written like this instead, *with* a trailing slash:

```
RewriteRule ^folder/?$ /otherfolder/anotherfolder/ [L]
```

You will likely need the `L` (or `END`) flag if you have other directives.